# surface area of a cylinder

Tags: integration

Find the surface area of the part of the plane [image]
that lies inside the cylinder [image]

I couldnt find the way to start but I believe that there should be a double integral!

Answer (score 0):

Recall the surface area formula:

[image: integral]

$z=3-3y-5x$, so $f_y=-3, f_x=-5$.

So we have $$S=\int_{-4}^4\int_{-\sqrt{16-x^2}}^{\sqrt{16-x^2}}\sqrt{(-3)^2+(-5)^2+1}dydx$$ $$=\int_{-4}^4\int_{-\sqrt{16-x^2}}^{\sqrt{16-x^2}}\sqrt{35}dydx$$
$$=\int_{-4}^4\sqrt{35}(2\sqrt{16-x^2})dydx$$
$$=2\sqrt{35}(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{16-x^2}x+8sin^{-1}(\frac{x}{4}))|_{-4}^4dydx.$$
$$=16\sqrt{35}\pi.$$

Can you take it from there? Comment if you need any clarification.

Comment: I really appreciate your help but there might be something wrong with it because I got a wrong answer

Comment: I got 8519.154888 for the final answer and its wrong!

Comment: Double check your calculation. It should be roughly 297.375.

Comment: yeah my calculation were wrong thanks I really appreciate that!